# A pandas-y way to find subjects that satisfy certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm sorry if this is too basic but I'm a complete newbie to python (especially pandas).

I have a sample data of college students' grades in humanities and math. I want to find (a) the students who have taken at least one course in both fields (b) the students who have not taken any humanities courses but have taken at least one math course.

Below is the first 3 rows of pd.DataFrame students:

```
Med Humanities               Math
    History Sociology Ethics Calculus LA  Statistics
ID                                              
1   90      96        94     90       91  NaN
2   85      81        NaN    98       NaN 95
3   NaN     NaN       NaN    NaN      70  NaN
```

Below is what I wrote. This does the job but I want to know if there is a more pandas-y way that doesn't use for-loops and if-conditions.

```
bothHS = []
startS = []

for row, col in students.iterrows():
    if pd.notna(col[0:3]).sum()>0:
        if pd.notna(col[3:6]).sum()>0: bothHS.append(row)
    else:
        if pd.notna(col[3:6]).sum()>0: startS.append(row)
```

After this, I also want to find those who have taken other course combinations, e.g. (i) History and LA or (ii) Sociology, Calculus and Statistics. For that, I added even more if-conditions which are making it even more messy. Is there any built-in pandas functions that handle such stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `&` and `|` operations to select for e.g. the students who have not taken any humanities courses but have taken at least one math course.

```
df.loc[(df[('Humanities', 'History')] == np.nan) & (df[('Humanities', 'Sociology')] == np.nan) & (df[('Humanities', 'Ethics')] == np.nan) & ((df[('Math', 'Calculus')] != np.nan) | (df[('Math', 'LA')] != np.nan) | (df[('Math', 'Statistics')] != np.nan))]
```

Comment: This does what I wanted. Thank you. I have another related question. Instead of the students, if I simply want the count, is there any other way to find it other than using the len function?

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to SO. If it helped resolve your issue, you want to check the green mark. This will help keep the focus on unanswered questions. Regarding your question, `len` is a simple way and efficient way to get the count.